# How Android App Updates Work

Tags: android

If I create an app, when I make an updated version will this replace the original? Or do I edit specific parts?

Comment: It is not 100% clear what are you talking about.

Comment: If I publish an app in the market then create an update is what I am referring to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, looks like you are talking about an update on device (without an uninstall). It will replace the app on device, however any files created by the previous version will survive the upgrade (including your shared preferences and DB files).

Comment: So as far as code changes are limited to Java files or XMLs(String, resources etc.) there is no extra efforts needed ? New .apk file will have new class files and new XMLs which will overwrite previous ones.   So publishing new .apk  is sufficient as part of updates ?

Comment: @KaushikLele Yes, it should work fine. Just bear in mind that all the user data will survive the update. So if you, for instance, change DB scheme, than don't forget to handle a DB migration. Or if you changed SharedPrefenences names or keys, then think twice on possible issues.

Comment: @Arhimed I have noticed that the updates are very small, sometimes only 1-2 mb in size compared to the original app which is 25-30 mb. So, these are partial updates then I presume.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it will replace the original